# Getting a HTTP ERROR 404 when I try to download Rational Test Workbench for Android. Why?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww, rational-test-workbench

I am using IBM Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight 8.5.10 plugin for Eclipse and I am trying to add a device using my PC. I've done the same process on a Mac and it works fine no issues. However on my PC when I go to the Workbench URL in a browser, phone, or emulator I go to start the download and I receive this on all devices...

> HTTP ERROR: 404 Problem accessing
>   /android/client/com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.client.ui-release.apk.
>   Reason:
>
> ```
> Not Found
> ```

Does anybody have any idea why I would be getting this?

Comment: Do you mean you are getting the error when you try to install IBM MTW into eclipse? Are you following these steps to install: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/install-imtww.html

Comment: Thanks for responding, but no. I have the Workbench plugin installed correctly into Eclipse. My problem is trying to install the IBM Rational Test Workbench Mobile app on an Android device.

Comment: The question's title tells a different story; Can you please edit and rephrase the question?

Comment: Idan Adar, when I want to add a device to the Test Workbench inside Eclipse it gives me a dialog box with an IP address. I take that IP address and put it into my browser and it displays a web page that gives me two options "Proceed with Android" or "Proceed with iOS". Naturally I choose Android because I'm on a PC. I'm then taken to the next page and I click download and that is where I get the 404. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and errors I finally fixed my issue. Here's the last thing I did to get it working. I uninstalled everything from Java, Eclipse, and IBM. I then reinstalled everything and placed Eclipse in My Documents and I changed Java versions to 1.6. After all of that it seems to be working fine. It doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

a good idea would be to check if your firewall is not blocking port 7878 or 8080 (the ones that are used by MTWW to communicate between device and workbench)

simple test for that : stop your firewall for 5 minutes, retry

if it works, it mean you'll have to configure this firewall to open this port

if you can't open this specific port, you can configure MTWW to change the default communication port (to use one that is open in your firewall) like this :

- in MTW, open : windows => preferences => Test => performance Test
  Report => Web report
- check "Allow remote access from a web browser"
- check "no security is required to access reports"
- change value of    "non-secure port" (default = 8080)
- when done, it would be better to restart MTWW before retrying

if all of this fail, last solution is to manually install the client apk

apk is located there :

[IBM shared dir of your install]\plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.runtime_[some version number]\client

apk to install : com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.client.ui-release.apk

the simpler is use "adb connect [your device ip]" (if adb is not yet connected to your device), then "adb install [apkname]"

Jerome B.

Comment: Jerome B. I turned off my firewall, but it's still not working. I also went through the steps you set out and that's not working either. I am able to find the apk manually, but this method is unacceptable in a corporate environment. Thanks for your reply. I have a Mac that I didn't have to change anything it just worked. I have two PC's on two different networks that are giving me the same result. This is very odd... Any other suggestions?

Comment: basic question : did you checked "Unknown sources" in your device settings ?(usually under "security" section, but location may change depending on device, android version and constructor layer)

Comment: I did Jerome. I get the 404 page no matter if I use a device, emulator, or my desktop. :/ It's weird because I'm able to bring up the first page and second page, but when I click download it gives me the 404 Error.

Comment: to help you futher, i would need 2 informations, that could explain what you see : first, the eclipse version you use, and second, the installation path for MTWW (if possible, i would need these information on your mac and on your pc). thank in advance

Comment: On both the Mac and PCs I’m using the latest version of Eclipse Kepler. I do not know the installation path of the MTWW. Thus I'm using what ever the default location is. I installed it straight from the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: ok, it's a known problem with Eclipse Kepler version : if eclipse installation path contains a space (as "program files"), this problem can occur. An easy workaround is to install eclipse in another location (as c:\eclipse)